# How to get frequency of sound using Zero crossing

Tags: python, audio, frequency, pyaudio

I am currently trying to get the frequency of the audio data that I have obtained from pyAudioStream.read(). I have already gotten the number of zero crosses there were in the chunk but now I want to determine the frequency based on the zero crosses, I heard it was possible but idk how to do it and I cant seem to find it on a google search, can anyone help me out here?

Comment: I suggest you eyeball a typical audio file you anticipate encountering using in a tool like Audacity to confirm this approach will work ... on simple pure tones it will work however on muddy real world audio the waveform may very well zero cross often even when the dominant frequency suggests a lower cross rate ... which if true you may need to use the more resource demanding FFT approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let assume that the variable `num_crossings` holds the number of zero crossings in your chunk.

Therefore, you have:

```
frequency = (num_crossings * sampling_rate / (2 * (len(chunk))))
```

For frequency detection, you can also use Fourier transform (with `numpy.fft` for instance).